# numpy.diff produces unexpected results

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, difference

I have a weird problem with numpy.diff function: when i applied it to a ndarray the result isn't meaningful. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

```
In [51]: y[0:20] 
Out[51]: array([ -1.74298015,   0.48808889,  3.55711794,   1.60425756,
        -2.16230544,  -2.72043361,  -7.74136894,  -8.29849524,
       -12.89580717,  -6.89705648,  -6.20016809,  -6.26981107,
        -4.94272368,  -8.28289977, -11.47886103, -18.14762649,
       -12.16312638,  -1.5986488 ,  -2.43279408,  -3.47560131])

In [52]: np.diff(y, 10)[0:10] 
Out[52]: array([ -955.00831582, 1226.29625361, -1419.52874856,  1391.47262492,
        -998.29181321,   363.19533892,   209.27652021,  -575.33795591,
         812.13066033,  -883.15925885])

In [53]: type(y) 
Out[53]: numpy.ndarray
```

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Comment: Start with a smaller `n`, like 1, then 2 etc.  It's hard to guess what `n=10` should produce.

Comment: I misunderstood the meaning of the second parameter. Dr.V's answer below clarifies it for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a guessing game here, but what `diff` does with a second parameter is to apply itself recursively (see here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html). So this one:

```
y = diff(x, 10)
print(y)
```

it's a short version of this

```
y = x
for _ in range(10):
    y = diff(y)
print(y)
```

Maybe what you expect is something like this:

```
y = x[10:] - x[:-10]
print(y)
```